# Set default Download path using selenium web driver-Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

how can I override the default download path?  (Using latest Chrome driver-2.35).
Thee code below puts files in the default download location instead of the specified one.

```
driver.get("page where download file exists");
driver.findElement(By.id("btnDownload")).click();
String downloadFilepath = "D:\\web driver\\";
Map<String, Object> preferences = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
preferences.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
//preferences.put("download.prompt_for_download", "false");
preferences.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);
System.out.println(downloadFilepath);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", preferences);
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, you are using the latest `Selenium` version. The old method of just building with `Capabilities` is deprecated. You should use `ChromeOptions` instead.

Try this and it should download the file in your `D` drive.

```
        String downloadFilepath = "D:\\web driver\\";
        Map<String, Object> preferences = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
        preferences.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
        preferences.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", preferences);

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "<your driver path>");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options); //Launch the browser

        driver.get("page where download file exists");
        driver.findElement(By.id("btnDownload")).click();
```